# gdb equivalent for VC++ cl compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdb, nmake

I am in the process of porting my application from "MinGW/GCC/make" to "cl compiler/nmake" chain tool.
I extensively used "gdb" for debugging in Linux/MinGW environments.
What is the command-line tool for debugging applications compiled with "cl compiler" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [CDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff539051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(although I never used it).
But you should take a look at windbg. The tool is bundled with the platform [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en) and is IMHO the best debugger for the windows platform.